# Reset "review queue"

Tags: support

I recently acquired the "review queue" privilege and looked at a queue (new user posts).  Just wanting to view without changing, I pressed "skip" for them all.  Is there a way to put them back in the queue if I now wanted to take an action on one?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't force that as far as I'm aware. If noone reviews those questions within a certain time they will reappear in your review queue.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear whether I'd cleared them from everybody's queue or not.